# Error 18456 Serverity 14, State 38

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, error-handling

I have an application that logs into SQL Server 2014 that uses a single login to access the database when a user opens up the application.  In other words I have 6 users using the same application with different logins, but the application itself is logging into SQL server with a single login.

One of my users is having issues.  When she logs into application the first time, she gets in fine, but if she tries to reopen it, it fails.  If she reboots her computer, she can log in one time again.  (Not acceptable)

The errors I'm seeing in the SQL Error logs are

> Error 18456; Severity 14; State 38
>   Error 18451, Severity 14; State 1
>   Error 18056; Severity: 20, State 23
>   Error: 18456; Severity: 14 State: 23

Comment: Are you properly disposing of your connection on app close?

Answer (score 3):

One location for finding out about many of these states is a post by Aaron Bertrand at:

- https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456

The error you are asking about are:

> Error: 18456; Severity: 14 State: 23
>
> Access to server validation failed while revalidating the login on the
> connection.
>
> Error 18456; Severity 14; State 38
> Failed to open the database specified in the login properties. (or)  Cannot open database "" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> Error 18056; Severity: 20, State 23

This is apparently related to connection pooling when the client could not reuse a spid.   If this is the same problem you can look at this Microsoft Connect item, but it has been closed as "Not Reproducible."

- https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/468478/sql-server-2008-periodically-does-not-accept-connections

and then:

> Error 18451, Severity 14; State 1
>
> SQL Server is in the process of shutting down. During shutdown, only members of the sysadmin fixed server role can make new connections.

This suggests that your installation needs some examination and perhaps updated to a more recent patch level.

Comment: we are at service patch 1. I'll apply the sp1 cumulative update #3.